# Why doesn't the GOsummaries function work with my gene lists? INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: r, bioconductor

I need to compare two sets of genes with the GOsummaries library. I have obtained the two gene lists with the R function "enrichGO". In the user guide of the GOsummaries library it says the following to create a gosummaries object:

"The gosummaries function requires a set of gene lists as an input. It applies GO enrichment
analysis to these gene lists using g:Profiler (http://biit.cs.ut.ee/gprofiler/) web toolkit and
saves the results into a gosummaries object. Then one can add experimental data and
configure the slots for additional information."

Inside g:Profiler (http://biit.cs.ut.ee/gprofiler/) I have tested my two gene lists and I get one result for each, so, I don't know, but I don't think it's the fault of that.

I show the two gene lists:

```
trad_genes$SYMBOL
```

```
 [1] "AKAP7"     "ARHGAP5"   "ATXN7"     "BAZ2A"     "CHD6"      "CNTLN"     "DDX3Y"    
 [8] "ELK4"      "ERICH1"    "ERICH1"    "FKBP8"     "GSE1"      "HOMER1"    "LINC01004"
[15] "NCAPG"     "NUB1"      "PDHX"      "POLD1"     "RAB3D"     "RAD54L2"   "SAFB"     
[22] "SH2B3"     "SLC38A1"   "SLC39A8"   "TXLNGY"    "UTY"       "ZFY"
```

```
genes_pvalue_EA$SYMBOL
```

```
  [1] "AAGAB"     "AKAP10"    "AKAP8L"    "AKR1A1"    "ANAPC1"    "ANKRD26"   "ANKRD27"  
  [8] "ANP32B"    "AP3B1"     "APOOL"     "APPL1"     "ARHGAP42"  "ATAD2"     "ATAD5"    
 [15] "ATF7IP2"   "ATG4C"     "ATL2"      "ATRIP"     "ATXN3"     "B4GALT5"   "BAZ1B"    
 [22] "BBS9"      "BCLAF3"    "BUD23"     "C5"        "CA13"      "CAMTA1"    "CAPRIN2"  
 [29] "CBR4"      "CCDC88A"   "CCDC88C"   "CENPH"     "CENPI"     "CHD2"      "COG3"     
 [36] "CPSF2"     "CSTF3"     "CUL1"      "CUL2"      "CUL3"      "DCAF7"     "DDX21"    
 [43] "DDX60"     "DHDDS"     "DIPK2A"    "DMTN"      "DNAJC2"    "EHBP1"     "ELF2"     
 [50] "ELK4"      "ERMARD"    "ERMARD"    "ESPL1"     "FAM168B"   "FAM193A"   "FAM216A"  
 [57] "FANCM"     "FBXO33"    "FBXW7"     "FKBP3"     "FOXJ3"     "FRMD4A"    "FUNDC1"   
 [64] "GIMAP8"    "GLS"       "GLYR1"     "GRHPR"     "GTF2IP1"   "GTPBP10"   "HECTD2"   
 [71] "HIP1"      "IKZF1"     "ITGB3BP"   "KATNAL1"   "KDM3B"     "KDM4C"     "KHDC4"    
 [78] "KHDRBS1"   "KIAA2026"  "KIF24"     "LDLRAD4"   "LINC00910" "MAP3K5"    "MAP4K5"   
 [85] "MAPK9"     "MARCHF3"   "METTL25"   "MLH3"      "MMS19"     "MYCBP2"    "MYO19"    
 [92] "MYO19"     "MYO9A"     "MYSM1"     "NAA15"     "NBAS"      "NBEAL1"    "NCAPD3"   
 [99] "NCEH1"     "NCOR2"     "NEDD4L"    "NEK9"      "NEMF"      "NIPBL"     "NMRAL1"   
[106] "NMRAL1"    "NMRK1"     "NPEPPS"    "NPLOC4"    "NSD2"      "NSUN6"     "NUP43"    
[113] "NUP88"     "OTUD7B"    "PACRGL"    "PAM"       "PAXBP1"    "PAXBP1"    "PCCA"     
[120] "PCGF6"     "PDPK2P"    "PGS1"      "PHACTR4"   "PIAS1"     "PIP4K2B"   "PIP4K2B"  
[127] "POLB"      "PRKCSH"    "PTK2"      "PTPN7"     "PUS7"      "RAB21"     "RAB27A"   
[134] "RABGAP1L"  "RAD51C"    "RALGAPA1"  "RALGAPB"   "RASGRP3"   "RBBP8"     "RBL1"     
[141] "RBM41"     "REV3L"     "RNPS1"     "RTN4"      "SAP130"    "SCAF8"     "SCARF1"   
[148] "SCARF1"    "SCLT1"     "SGO1"      "SIAE"      "SIRT1"     "SKA3"      "SLAIN1"   
[155] "SLC15A4"   "SLC37A3"   "SLC39A11"  "SLC39A11"  "SLC6A9"    "SLCO4C1"   "SMARCD1"  
[162] "SOS2"      "SPG11"     "SPG7"      "SUPT20H"   "SUZ12P1"   "SYPL1"     "TARS2"    
[169] "TBX21"     "TIAL1"     "TMCC2"     "TMEM209"   "TMEM41B"   "TNFRSF21"  "TNPO2"    
[176] "TOGARAM1"  "TPRA1"     "TRA2B"     "TRAPPC9"   "TRIM33"    "TSC22D1"   "TTPAL"    
[183] "TUT7"      "TXLNG"     "U2AF1"     "UBE2G1"    "UBR3"      "USP31"     "USP6NL"   
[190] "UTRN"      "VPS13A"    "WDPCP"     "WIPI1"     "WIPI2"     "WWC3"      "XPO1"     
[197] "YME1L1"    "ZBTB16"    "ZBTB8OS"   "ZC3H14"    "ZCCHC7"    "ZFX"       "ZFYVE1"   
[204] "ZNF451"
```

And the code I have tried to reproduce with them is as follows:

```
genes1 = trad_genes$SYMBOL
genes2 = genes_pvalue_EA$SYMBOL
gl = list(List = list(genes1, genes2))
gs = gosummaries(gl)
```

```
Warning: Please consider using the new package "gprofiler2". At the moment you are using a deprecated package relying on outdated data.
  More information at https://biit.cs.ut.ee/gprofiler/page/r-new. Feel free to contact us at biit.support@ut.ee for further help.
Error: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

But all I get is a warning and an error. The warning tells me to use "gprofiler2". But I tried to uninstall the "gprofiler" library and use only "gprofiler2" and the "GOsummaries" library doesn't work because it needs the "gprofiler" library. As for the INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, I don't know what to do.

I'm new asking on stackoverflow, but if some more information is needed to solve this I'm willing to give anything.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
> gostres_trad_genes <- gprofiler2::gost(trad_genes)
> gostres_trad_genes$result
    query significant    p_value term_size query_size intersection_size
1 query_1        TRUE 0.03019194       288         23                 5
2 query_1        TRUE 0.02249582       257         24                 5
  precision     recall               term_id source
1 0.2173913 0.01736111 MIRNA:hsa-miR-181d-5p  MIRNA
2 0.2083333 0.01945525             TF:M01882     TF
                               term_name effective_domain_size source_order
1                        hsa-miR-181d-5p                 14846          315
2 Factor: IRF-2; motif: NNRAAAGTGAAASNNA                 20011         4282
       parents
1 MIRNA:000000
2    TF:M00000
```

[image]

```
> gostres_genes_pvalue_EAs <- gprofiler2::gost(genes_pvalue_EA)
> gostres_genes_pvalue_EAs$result |> head()
    query significant      p_value term_size query_size intersection_size
1 query_1        TRUE 2.825648e-06      1276        184                35
2 query_1        TRUE 3.576819e-05      1273        184                33
3 query_1        TRUE 2.517966e-04       191        184                12
4 query_1        TRUE 6.533390e-04      1811        184                38
5 query_1        TRUE 7.115125e-04      3562        184                59
6 query_1        TRUE 1.906513e-03      1019        184                26
   precision     recall    term_id source
1 0.19021739 0.02742947 GO:0043687  GO:BP
2 0.17934783 0.02592302 GO:0022402  GO:BP
3 0.06521739 0.06282723 GO:1901875  GO:BP
4 0.20652174 0.02098288 GO:0007049  GO:BP
5 0.32065217 0.01656373 GO:0006996  GO:BP
6 0.14130435 0.02551521 GO:0070647  GO:BP
                                                       term_name
1                        post-translational protein modification
2                                             cell cycle process
3 positive regulation of post-translational protein modification
4                                                     cell cycle
5                                         organelle organization
6   protein modification by small protein conjugation or removal
  effective_domain_size source_order                            parents
1                 21010        11358                         GO:0036211
2                 21010         6908             GO:0007049, GO:0009987
3                 21010        22698 GO:0031401, GO:0043687, GO:1901873
4                 21010         2692                         GO:0009987
5                 21010         2654                         GO:0016043
6                 21010        17034                         GO:0043687
> gprofiler2::gostplot(gostres_genes_pvalue_EAs)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(trad_genes)
c("AKAP7", "ARHGAP5", "ATXN7", "BAZ2A", "CHD6", "CNTLN", "DDX3Y", 
"ELK4", "ERICH1", "ERICH1", "FKBP8", "GSE1", "HOMER1", "LINC01004", 
"NCAPG", "NUB1", "PDHX", "POLD1", "RAB3D", "RAD54L2", "SAFB", 
"SH2B3", "SLC38A1", "SLC39A8", "TXLNGY", "UTY", "ZFY")
> dput(genes_pvalue_EA)
c("AAGAB", "AKAP10", "AKAP8L", "AKR1A1", "ANAPC1", "ANKRD26", 
"ANKRD27", "ANP32B", "AP3B1", "APOOL", "APPL1", "ARHGAP42", "ATAD2", 
"ATAD5", "ATF7IP2", "ATG4C", "ATL2", "ATRIP", "ATXN3", "B4GALT5", 
"BAZ1B", "BBS9", "BCLAF3", "BUD23", "C5", "CA13", "CAMTA1", "CAPRIN2", 
"CBR4", "CCDC88A", "CCDC88C", "CENPH", "CENPI", "CHD2", "COG3", 
"CPSF2", "CSTF3", "CUL1", "CUL2", "CUL3", "DCAF7", "DDX21", "DDX60", 
"DHDDS", "DIPK2A", "DMTN", "DNAJC2", "EHBP1", "ELF2", "ELK4", 
"ERMARD", "ERMARD", "ESPL1", "FAM168B", "FAM193A", "FAM216A", 
"FANCM", "FBXO33", "FBXW7", "FKBP3", "FOXJ3", "FRMD4A", "FUNDC1", 
"GIMAP8", "GLS", "GLYR1", "GRHPR", "GTF2IP1", "GTPBP10", "HECTD2", 
"HIP1", "IKZF1", "ITGB3BP", "KATNAL1", "KDM3B", "KDM4C", "KHDC4", 
"KHDRBS1", "KIAA2026", "KIF24", "LDLRAD4", "LINC00910", "MAP3K5", 
"MAP4K5", "MAPK9", "MARCHF3", "METTL25", "MLH3", "MMS19", "MYCBP2", 
"MYO19", "MYO19", "MYO9A", "MYSM1", "NAA15", "NBAS", "NBEAL1", 
"NCAPD3", "NCEH1", "NCOR2", "NEDD4L", "NEK9", "NEMF", "NIPBL", 
"NMRAL1", "NMRAL1", "NMRK1", "NPEPPS", "NPLOC4", "NSD2", "NSUN6", 
"NUP43", "NUP88", "OTUD7B", "PACRGL", "PAM", "PAXBP1", "PAXBP1", 
"PCCA", "PCGF6", "PDPK2P", "PGS1", "PHACTR4", "PIAS1", "PIP4K2B", 
"PIP4K2B", "POLB", "PRKCSH", "PTK2", "PTPN7", "PUS7", "RAB21", 
"RAB27A", "RABGAP1L", "RAD51C", "RALGAPA1", "RALGAPB", "RASGRP3", 
"RBBP8", "RBL1", "RBM41", "REV3L", "RNPS1", "RTN4", "SAP130", 
"SCAF8", "SCARF1", "SCARF1", "SCLT1", "SGO1", "SIAE", "SIRT1", 
"SKA3", "SLAIN1", "SLC15A4", "SLC37A3", "SLC39A11", "SLC39A11", 
"SLC6A9", "SLCO4C1", "SMARCD1", "SOS2", "SPG11", "SPG7", "SUPT20H", 
"SUZ12P1", "SYPL1", "TARS2", "TBX21", "TIAL1", "TMCC2", "TMEM209", 
"TMEM41B", "TNFRSF21", "TNPO2", "TOGARAM1", "TPRA1", "TRA2B", 
"TRAPPC9", "TRIM33", "TSC22D1", "TTPAL", "TUT7", "TXLNG", "U2AF1", 
"UBE2G1", "UBR3", "USP31", "USP6NL", "UTRN", "VPS13A", "WDPCP", 
"WIPI1", "WIPI2", "WWC3", "XPO1", "YME1L1", "ZBTB16", "ZBTB8OS", 
"ZC3H14", "ZCCHC7", "ZFX", "ZFYVE1", "ZNF451")
```

Comment: It's a progress to see that my gene results work with gprofiler2, but what I really wanted was to use those two gene lists in the GOsummaries library (I don't know if you know it), which if I understand correctly is able to compare the two gene lists, or maybe it just does what you have done, I don't know. But thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @JoséAdriánPardoPérez I see. Probably gosummaries internally uses the older package, but not sure. Glad to have brought you some progress.